# Flutter Image Compression can't acces Android folder

Tags: flutter

I am using the Flutter Image Compression package
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress
to compress some images with the below code.
it is working correctly if the picked photos are anywhere on the device, except the folder "Internal Storage/Android"

if the image is anywhere inside this folder or its subfolders, the compression result is null.

while these Folders contain all images received through WhatsApp, users will need to use them.

any reason why? or how to solve it?

My assumption could be access permission to this folder but don't know if this is true.

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageslist.length; i++) {
    final filePath = imageslist[i].absolute.path;
    var extensionString =
        filePath.toString().substring(filePath.toString().length - 3);
    if (extensionString == "jpg" || extensionString == "peg") {
      final lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.jp'));
      final splitted = filePath.substring(0, (lastIndex));
      final outPath = "${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}";
      var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
        imageslist[i].absolute.path,
        outPath,
        quality: 50,
      );
      print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is in saving the file to folder of whatsapp, so instead I made all my photos to be saved after compression in a temp folder.

using path_provider package

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;
```